# The image of mapping $w=\frac{1}{z}$ with domain a circle $|z-1|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

The image of mapping $w=\frac{1}{z}$ with domain a circle $|z-1|=1$.
First, I have $z=e^{i\Theta} +1$ and input it to $w=\frac{1}{z}$, i get $w=\frac{1-e^{i\Theta}}{1-e^{i2\Theta}}$. But I didn't know how to get the range of it. give me a clue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $z-1=e^{2iA}$

$\dfrac1z=\dfrac1{1+e^{2iA}}=\dfrac1{1+\cos2A+i\sin2A}=\dfrac1{2\cos A(\cos A+i\sin A)}=\dfrac{\cos A-i\sin A}{2\cos A}=?$

Comment: so the answer is $w=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{tan A.i}{2}$ ?

Comment: @jamesbrown, Where $A=\dfrac12\cdot$arg$(z-1)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try writing the initial circle as $zz^*-z-z^*=0$ (why is this true?) and then replacing $z$ by $\frac{1}{w}$.